# Uncaught Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module in vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, cryptojs

[**Uncaught Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module in vscode**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X10)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdn6s.png)eN.png

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install the library using this command:

```
npm install crypto-js
```

Or if you're using yarn:

```
yarn add crypto-js
```